# How would I achieve a half screen scroll lock effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking to design a site that has a similar feature to this one:
http://combo.nyc/projects/chillhouse

I'd like to lock the scrolling on only one half of the page at a time. I've designed two panels .leftPanel and .rightPanel but I'm not sure how to get this effect. I'm assuming there's some way to get this through jquery but through my searching I haven't come up with a good way to do it smoothly and properly.

Would anybody be able to help direct me towards a good method or explain how I can attach this functionality into my site?

Thanks!

Comment: _"I haven't come up with a good way to do it smoothly and properly"_ - So there's already a (more or less) working construct. Please add that to your question, because right now this is more of a _"do my work for me"_ request.

Comment: I don't actually have a working construct. I tried to build this using parallax effects and that simply will not work. It's not 10% of the way there it's legitimately further away to use that method than starting from scratch.

Since people will often try to suggest a hacked version of what you have up I find it more productive to not include broken code as a "sample". I'm legitimately curious to just hear "I'd use this function in X language" since I don't even know which road to go down.

Answer (score 0):

Use position: sticky with top: 0 and calculate the heights accordingly. No js required.

```css
.panelWrap{
  width: 100vw;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
.leftPanel{
  height: 100%;
  width: 50vw;
  float: left;
  background: green;
}
.rightPanel{
  height: 100%;
  width: 50vw;
  background: blue;
  float: right;
  height:
}
p{
height:100vh;
}
.is-sticky{
position: sticky;
top: 0;
background: red;
height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panelWrap">
  <div class="leftPanel">
  <p>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
</p>
  <div class="is-sticky">
    <p>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
</p>


</div>
 <p>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors
</p>
 <p>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
</p>

  </div>
  <div class="rightPanel">
   <p>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text.
</p>
 
<p>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
</p>  <div class="is-sticky">
     <p>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. 
</p>
</div><p>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
</p>
<p>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
</p>
<p>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
</p>
<p>Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not exactly the desired effect since this will literally force both sides to scroll independently. If you see the example they scroll at the same rate but then one side will "lock" and stop scrolling for a full screen height and then resume.

Comment: Check the example. It's not perfect but close.  You do not need to use any parallax or js. It's just based on calculating heights and using CSS position: sticky and top: 0.

Comment: Thanks Alisha that's a great example. I didn't know that was possible I really appreciate it!

Comment: Welcome. Happy to help. :-)